# How many Activities do I need?

Tags: android, android-activity, optimization

I'm in the middle of making my first Android app and have been asked to make an app that displays information on books. I currently have a login screen which brings me to a new page of buttons with different genres. When you click on a genre it brings you to a listview of books in that genre, you then click on a book and it should display information on that book.

My main issue is, I have made a lot a activities already and I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way? When I get to displaying information on each of the books that will be clicked inside of my listview, do I then have to make a new activity for each or is there a better way to do this that I seem to be missing?

Comment: You make 1 activity to display details for a book and reuse that for each book

Comment: **One** Activity, **many** (...) Fragments. Many: At least one, to as many as needed (try to make them parametric).

Comment: Can anyone explain why this question was voted down? How are new users, like myself, meant to understand how to correctly ask a question if get voted down with no explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

1. Create your first activity for Login (i.e LoginActivity.class)
2. Create your second activity that contains your genres (i.e GenresActivity.class)
3. Create your third activity that contains a list of books in that particular genre - remember this will be reused for all genres because it is simply a list of items. (Have you heard of RecyclerView instead of a ListView?)
4. Create your 4th activity for details of a book (i.e BookDetails.class) - this will also be reused each time to display a book's information. The caveat would be to have the same structure/layout used because a book object has the same information like title, author, year and perhaps cost. So, when a user clicks a book from a list, you want to direct them to a details view where they can view more information on that particular book!

That brings you to 4 activities - not too many if you think about it.

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. This has helped a lot. I thought I had to make a new activity for each rather than reusing ones I already had. I have not heard of RecyclerView but I will definitely look into it